# didn't show application, places etc things in ubuntu 11.10 desktop

Tags: 11.10

sir, am a new beginner in Linux. I installed ubuntu 11.10 in my pc and in the desktop menu bar it didn't show application, places etc things.. How to get this? Pls help me to solve this....

Comment: Click on the Ubuntu icon in the top left (see red arrow in the answer below). In the search panel that opens type help and click on the question mark (?) in the blue circle and read the Ubuntu Desktop Guide that will open on your desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Unity is the new kid on the block - http://unity.ubuntu.com/ . It's the default for Ubuntu 11.10 and you are most probably logged into it.

Click on the top-most button on the left-hand panel that has a Ubuntu logo or use your Super key (windows key) to launch the Dash and you can go to your programs and places from there.

[image: unity-panel-screenshot]

[image: dash_screenshot]